# Eclipse Matching Parenthesis before caret instead of after

Tags: c, eclipse, editor

Eclipse highlights the closing parenthesis when I place my caret after the opening one. Is there a way to change this to highlight the closing parenthesis when I place my cursor *before* the opening parenthesis instead of after?

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you want this?

Comment: I come from using Scitools Understand for my development and got used to seeing the parenthesis highlight when I place my caret before the opening one. No other reason other than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Eclipse for a couple of reasons:

- If you go to **Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor** and click the **?** button in the bottom right corner the help documentation states that if **Highlight matching brackets** is checked (which it is by default) then ***When the cursor is beside a bracket, the matching bracket is highlighted***. It doesn't say anything about the cursor having to be to the right of the bracket for this to work.
- Also, note that the matching bracket is highlighted in Java regardless of whether the cursor (caret) is to the left or right of the opening bracket, and it seems very unlikely that this behavior is deliberately different in Java vs. C/C++.

Feel free to [raise a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EPP) if you agree.

There is an alternative approach which doesn't do exactly what you want, but might be acceptable:

- Install the **Bracketeer for C/C++ (CDT)** plugin: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-cc-cdt
- Positioning the cursor to the left of a bracket still doesn't work!
- However, if you hover over the <s>caret</s> left bracket, or to the left of it, the plugin will highlight the matching closing bracket. Ironically, if you hover to the right of the caret it doesn't work. Here's sample screen shot after hovering to the left of an opening bracket:

[image: bracketeer]

- Note that this behavior is totally independent of the cursor position. In the screen shot above you can see that the cursor is on line 25.

**Bracketeer** comes with a lot of configurable options (**Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Bracketeer -> Bracket Highlighting / Hints**), so it might be worth a look:

[image: bracketeerConfig]